# CakePHP 4 ConsoleOptionParser usage

Tags: php, inheritance, cakephp, cakephp-4.x

In my CakePHP 4.0 project, and I'm trying to achieve what I think is a fairly trivial goal: I would like to have to have a "base" console command, with some basic setup, and other classes that extend it.

Specifically, I would like to define a [`ConsoleOptionParser`][1] in my base class, because all other Command classes should have access to the same options:

```
<?php

namespace Import\Shell;

use Cake\Command\Command;
use Cake\Console\ConsoleOptionParser;

class BaseImportCommand extends Command
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        // setup some stuff related to my project here
    }

    protected function buildOptionParser(ConsoleOptionParser $parser): ConsoleOptionParser
    {
        // Get an empty parser from the framework.
        $parser = parent::getOptionParser();

        // Define your options and arguments.
        $parser->addOptions(
            [
                'country' => [
                    'short' => 'c',
                    'help' => 'The country for which to execute the operation.',
                    'required' => false,
                ],
                'author' => [
                    'short' => 'a',
                    'help' => 'The ID of the author for which to execute the operation.',
                    'required' => false,
                ],
                'product' => [
                    'short' => 'p',
                    'help' => 'The ID of the product for which to execute the operation.',
                    'required' => false,
                ],
            ]
        );

        // Return the completed parser
        return $parser;
    }
}
```

```
<?php

namespace Import\Shell;

use Cake\Console\Arguments;
use Cake\Console\ConsoleIo;

class ProcessProductImagesCommand extends BaseImportCommand
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        // setup some more stuff here
    }

    /**
     * execute() method.
     *
     * @return bool|int|null Success or error code.
     */
    public function execute(Arguments $args, ConsoleIo $io)
    {
        $country = $args->getOption('country');
        $productId = $args->getOption('product');

        // do my logic here
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I run

```
bin/cake processProductImages -c CH
```

in the shell I get this error:

```
Error: Unknown short option `c`.
```

Why is that? I am not redefining the `buildOptionParser` method inside the `ProcessProductImagesCommand` class, so I would assume that the `ConsoleOptionParser` configuration is inherited from the `BaseCommand` class.

To fix the problem, I have tried adding this method to the `ProcessProductImagesCommand` class:

```
    protected function buildOptionParser(ConsoleOptionParser $parser): ConsoleOptionParser
    {
        return parent::buildOptionParser($parser);
    }
```

but what happens in this case when I run

```
bin/cake processProductImages -c CH
```

in the shell I then get this error:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in /var/www/repo/public/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Console/ConsoleOptionParser.php on line 430
```

I have found out the the only actual way to have the options that I need, in the classes that I need them, is to completely repeat the initialisation of the `ConsoleOptionParser` in the child class by copying the whole `buildOptionParser`  method from the `BaseImportCommand` class, but obviously I don't like this solution as it leads to useless code repetition.
[1]: https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/console-commands/option-parsers.html

Answer (score 0):

- By convention [**commands**](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/console-commands/commands.html#creating-a-command) are supposed to live in the `Command` namespace, not the `Shell` namespace.
- You cannot call `parent::buildOptionParser()` without any arguments.
- The first argument of `addArgument()` is meant to be a string, or an instance of `\Cake\Console\ConsoleInputArgument`, not an array. [**Multiple arguments**](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/console-commands/option-parsers.html#adding-multiple-arguments) can be added at once using the `addArguments()` method (note the trailing `s`).
- [**Arguments**](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/console-commands/option-parsers.html#using-arguments) (positional values) and [**options**](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/console-commands/option-parsers.html#using-options) are two different things, `-c` is an option that needs to be configured using `addOption()`.
- If you're exhausting 130+ MB of memory in the options parsing stage, then you possibly created an infinite loop.

Comment: You're right, I should have been using `addOptions` instead of `addArgument`. But, I replaced it and I get the same `Allowed memory size exhausted` error.